# Using jQuery validate on select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-validate

I have the following javascript:

```
var $step = $(".wizard-step:visible:last"); // get current step

        var validator = $("#WizardForm").validate(); // obtain validator
        var anyError = false;
        $step.find("input").each(function ()
        {
            if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
                anyError = true;
            }

        });
```

This is successfully validating all my input fields but upon trying to apply a similar method to the select type using code:

```
$step.find("select").each(function () {
    if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
        anyError = true;
    }
});
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="wizard-step" id="step1" visibility="hidden" style="display: block;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 column ui-sortable">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Tariff_Type">Tariff Type</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select style="width:100%;height:35px;border-radius:4px;padding-left:10px;" id="TariffType" name="TariffType" class="form-control input required">
                            <option value="">Please Select Tariff Type</option>
                            <option value="keypad account">Say Hello To Budget Extra Discount</option>
                            <option value="bill pay account">Standard 24H</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="TariffType" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I ensure that a TariffType value is selected using this method?

Comment: Only show us the **rendered** HTML output as that's the only thing your JavaScript can see/use anyway.

Comment: Ive updated the HTML to show rendered HTML

Comment: Have you tried this yet:  `if (! $(this).valid()) { ...`

Comment: Perhaps I just need to include a check to see whether the select exists in the DIV before attaching the validator? As there are some DIVs that have no selects while there are not any DIVs which have no inputs

Comment: But if the `select` doesn't exist, then there is nothing there to pass/fail validation and your code would be working, no?  In other words, since the validator will automatically ignore hidden/missing/invisible, etc, it would not matter if you check for its existence first.

Comment: Cheers Sparky that did the trick

Comment: The `.valid()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `.valid()` method instead...

```
if (! $(this).valid()) { ...
```